# MariaDB seems to be locking all the tables

Tags: mariadb, locking, memory, xampp

I am running MariaDB locally on
windows 10. XAMPP version 3.2.4 and MariaDB Version 10.4.7

I am moving MYISAM tables to INNODB and trying to prove that the locking issues we seem to be having will be mitigated by this move. To test that I wrote the following code "locking" code

```
SELECT * FROM temp
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM dbtable 
                 WHERE recordid=1 ) AS YY ON recordid=44564733
```

table temp is a large table and table dbtable is the table I am "locking". It is unique on recordid.

I run this code in one session of my wesbite and then on another session I update dbtable2 with

```
INSERT INTO dbtable2 (field1) values ("hello")
```

The insert is made using PHP mysqli.

dbtable can be ANY table in my database. It will block the update for dbtable2 until select finishes. I would have expected this locking to have happened if dbtable and dbtable2 were the same and the table engine was MYISAM.
BUT for me dbtable can be any table and engine can be either MYISAM or INNODB, the update will not happen until select finishes.

If I run the "locking" code (Select) on my website and then access my db via HEIDISQL and run the update query there, the update happens straightaway.
So this leads me to believe there is something happening in maybe PHP or its somehow memory related.
Any help appreciated.

- GENERAL LOG FILE

```
            48 Query    SET NAMES utf8
            48 Init DB  dbname
            48 Query    SELECT * FROM Temp LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE  RecordID=1) AS Rec ON  RecordID=1 
211113 16:36:59     49 Connect  root@localhost as anonymous on dbname
            49 Query    SET NAMES utf8
            49 Init DB  dbname
            50 Connect  pma@localhost as anonymous on 
            51 Connect  root@localhost as anonymous on 
            51 Query    SELECT @@version, @@version_comment
            51 Query    SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
            51 Query    SET lc_messages = 'en_US'
            50 Query    SELECT `config_data`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timevalue`) ts FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig` WHERE `username` = 'root'
            51 Query    SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
            51 Quit 
            50 Quit  
211113 16:37:06     48 Quit  
211113 16:37:07     46 Quit 
            52 Connect  root@localhost as anonymous on dbname
            52 Query    SET NAMES utf8
            52 Init DB  myfreeway
            52 Query    SET NAMES 'utf8'
            52 Quit 
            53 Connect  root@localhost as anonymous on dbname
            53 Query    SET NAMES utf8
            53 Init DB  dbname
            53 Query    INSERT statment of dbtable2
            53 Quit 
            49 Quit
```

Comment: I suggest you enable the [general_log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html) and tail the log file to see what SQL statements are really running. If PHP or your PHP framework is doing something on its own, this will reveal it.

Comment: Would that be a very old version of XAMPP, the 3.2.4 ?

Comment: Doe either table have an index starting with `recordid`?

Comment: Would you mind verifying your version of XAMPP?

Comment: It could be your PHP has only one database connection and has to execute the commands sequentially.

Comment: I'm trying to verify your configuration, but I can't find version 3.2.4: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/

Comment: Hi All. I have scoured the internet and I think I may have found the issue. The issue could be nothing to do with db locking but with php and start_session. Reading https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php with a post made 10 years ago it may be SESSION blocking related. I will test and report back.

Comment: I would have expected your update and your select to have different session IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the query more complex than it needs to be:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM temp AS t
    JOIN dbtable AS d  ON t.??? = d.???  -- How are the tables related??
    WHERE ??.recordid=1
      AND ??.recordid=44564733
```

The `ON` clause probably says that the two tables line up on some column.

The `WHERE` clause is for filtering.  It does not make sense to look at "recorded" twice.  Please describe what you are doing.

Each table needs a `PRIMARY KEY` (which is necessarily "unique" and is an "index").  You probably need an index on `recordid` and what ever is in the `ON` clause.

Yes, it will "block until it finishes", but with a suitable index, it may be very fast.

Comment: So, you can't do an update while another query is running?

Comment: That's not quite the case.  First, let's fix the query and discuss more details.

Comment: You may want to read the OP. I find it rather puzzling. BTW, would MySQL (or MariaDB) notice your query will never return results and not execute it?

Comment: Hi. I realise my query is very odd. The two tables are not related at all. This was the only way I could simulate a "lock" on dbtable.  I ran this code in one session of my website and tried to update dbtable on another session. dbtable is a INNODB table so I expected it to update without issues. What is happening is that the update waits for the query to end and then update is executed. I then realised dbtable could be any table and not just the table I was updating. The update would only happen once query finished. I am doing this to prove a move from MYISAM to INNODB prevents locking .. hmm

Comment: @Harj - "a move from MYISAM to INNODB prevents locking" -- "table locks" go away, but "row locks" will happen.  Row locks are _usually_ less harmful.  Some "row locks" feel like "table locks".

Comment: @RickJames thanks but the weird thing is that the two tables are totally unrelated. I could understand if the tables were the same but how can locking one table influence the other

Comment: Hi all . I have added GENERAL LOG to the initial. Really sorry I didnt know how to format at correctly. I kicked off the "lock" and then the update. But from log you can see process wait to finish lock first and then executes the update. See line 50 Quit  211113 16:37:06        48 Quit  211113 16:37:07        46 Quit. Locking finishes 16:37:06 and then update starts 16:37:07. Could this be a PHP issue??

Comment: @Harj - A "cross join" takes a long time and may lock all rows in both tables for the entire time.

Comment: @RickJames. The point I am trying to get across is that this is locking more than just the two tables. It seems to be locking all tables . The GENERAL LOG file I attached to my initial issue shows that three tables are involved. Two are used in the locking and third one is being updated. Only when the locks are released on the two tables will system allow the update which doesnt make sense unless something else is going on.

Comment: @Harj - Connections 46 and 48 may have been conflicting; connection 53 (the Insert) started later and finished rapidly -- it was not involved with 46 and 48.  What else was 46 doing?

Comment: @RickJames. 46 is "Connect root@localhost as anonymous on dbname". Could it be that the connection to the database by both the SELECT statement and INSERT statement cannot happen at the same time with root@localhost?. The select connects to the database (46) and initiates the select. A second later I kick off the "INSERT". Looks like INSERT is waiting for the connection to the db to be released "46 Quit" before it gets it and does the INSERT. Is this the issue? Do I need to use two different logins into the database not just root?

Comment: @Harj - I don't think so.  Whether "root" or not, I can't think of anything that will simply wait for a connection to finish before doing something.  If there are currently "too many connections", an attempt at a connecting will fail.  No Insert (etc) will care about connections, only about locked rows.  So... I think that what you are seeing with "46" is a coincidence.

Comment: @RickJames thanks for all your input much appreciated. I am at a loss as to what is happening. I have no idea how to resolve this.

Comment: Perhaps you could answer my questions.

Comment: sorry @GerardH.Pille. I will answers your questions. XAMPP v 3.2.4.  Question about my php having only one db connection. Everytime it needs a connection it gets it. I am not sure if there is a setting anywhere that determines this. If there is please share.  Whether SQL gets executed. It defintely gets executed as I "lock" is in place as it whirs round the select. The update takes place as record gets updated

Comment: Please continue under your original post.  There is no version 3.2.4.

Comment: Apologies 3.2.4 is the xampp control panel version. XAMPP version is 7.2.33

Comment: @Harj - The select you have presented does not make sense; we need to figure out how it should be written.  Please describe the intent of it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly thanks to everyone who tried to help. Secondly apologies for assuming it was a DB issue as I was working on changing DB table Engine from MyISAM to InnoDB to remove locking and testing suggesting locking was worse as a result.

The issue is to do with PHP SESSION parameters. With `session_start()` system locks the session file until released when query finishes. With slow running query this prevents other sessions from getting hold of the session table. Trick is to use `session_write_close()`. All explained by [this clever saviour](https://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/).

But be aware that starting and closing may have its own drawbacks.
Following extract from [the PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

> PHP adds another identical session cookie to the response header on every session_start. Do this enough times, and your response header becomes big enough to choke the web server.

I will experiment more but for the time being this has been resolved.